# Remove text after a codeword

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of company names that have been sent with their added company numbers. How can I remove these company numbers (of different length) in SQL?
"Limited" if in the name needs to be called "LTD".

For example:

```
Company_name
MORTISON & CO MANAGEMENT LIMITED - FSP986
SALT MANAGEMENT LIMITED  FSP33457
Nes Wiki  FSP23423435
```

and I need

```
MORTISON & CO MANAGEMENT LTD
SALT MANAGEMENT LTD
Nes Wiki  FSP23423435
```

The change from "Limited" to "LTD" I can do with a case when clause
But how do I remove everything from - FSP pr FSP?

I tried a piece of code I found in two different pages, but it renders empty cells. Can I not use '%' to get rid of the various lengths of numbers? I left the -x  prior to the last bracket out as I don't know the length or number of digits. How do I deal with the fact that I sometimes have FSP and sometimes - FSP

```
 , LEFT(Company_name, CHARINDEX('FSP%',Company_name) )
```

Comment: Is this a one item update or an ongoing process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `patindex()` for more flexibility.  However, you really need to check for different possibilities:

```
select (case when company_name like '% - FSP[0-9]%'
             then trim(left(company_name, patindex('% - FSP[0-9]%', company_name)))
             when company_name like '% FSP[0-9]%'
             then trim(left(company_name, patindex('% FSP[0-9]%', company_name)))
             else company_name
        end)
```

It can also be done with `charindex()`, but that doesn't give the flexibility to look for a number after the FSP:

```
select (case when company_name like '% - FSP%'
             then trim(left(company_name, charindex(' - FSP', company_name)))
             when company_name like '% FSP%'
             then trim(left(company_name, charindex(' FSP', company_name)))
             else company_name
        end)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=422173a6113b4adfa6b8efd9f9b41e5c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: great, I just had to change the trim to ltrim as it complained that  'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Anna . . . `trim()` was introduced quite recently.